# iPhone -iAd, Admob and local ads

Tags: iphone, admob, iad

I am about to integrate iAd in one of my apps. My idea is to build a mechanism that always try to load iAd first. If no iAd is available for a given user or time, an ad from AdMob is loaded. If no ad from Admob is available, then a local ad I will prepare, loads.

My question is: is there a way to create an ad using Admob that behaves like iOS Ads? I mean, that do not ejects the application and open safari or whatever?

If yes, is there any tutorial out there showing how to do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorial found here --> http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-integrate-iad-for-os32-and-admob.html